# Does anyone still hide JS from old browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser

Does anyone still use the old

```
<!-- hide JS from old browsers -->
```

trick?

As I recall, this was targeted at people who used Netscape, or IE4.

I just checked out our stats and in the last month we had more people visit the site using "Playstation Portable " (4 visits) as their user agent than we had using Netscape (1 visit).

Is there any point in me even having the "hide" thing in my javascript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you no longer need to do that.

[Crockford also says](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html)...

> Do not use the `<!-- //-->` hack with scripts. It was intended to prevent scripts from showing up as text on the first generation browsers Netscape 1 and Mosaic. It has not been necessary for many years. `<!-- //-->` is supposed to signal an HTML comment. Comments should be ignored, not compiled and executed. Also, HTML comments are not to include `--`, so a script that decrements has an HTML error.

Comment: For all intents and purposes, Crockford reinvented the internet.  He's the main reason why I even care about JavaScript.

Comment: the example i gave does not suffer from the problem mentioned because it's further wrapped in a CDATA block. i lifted the example from the Drupal developers.

Answer (score 3):

No. {insert extra chars here to meet limit for SO}

Comment: Could use the extra space for a citation or more explanation.

Comment: @John K - I don't believe more explanation is necessary. He knows why it used to be done, he wonders if that still a concern. I (firmly) believe it is no longer a concern.

Comment: FWIW I +1'd the explanation w/ Crockford citation last night. Doesn't change my answer, though.

Comment: Although I agree with your answer, I generally don't agree with subjective statements without argument or proof behind them. Somebody else could come along and say `Yes. {insert extra chars here to meet limit for SO}`. Comparing two such answers is next to impossible for a reader who stumbles upon this thread for a quality answer. However the needed context for the authour's question has been provided in other answers and they've been up-voted accordingly - as per usual the quality of the answer is proven by community voting.

Answer (score 2):

The way I figure it, if you're designing an application with which one of the main selling points is javascript-based interactivity, there's no point in catering to older browsers.

Still, it's important to know the specific goals of your product.  You need to know who you're targeting and make an informed decision as to whether or not it's worth it.

In any case, you should make an attempt to discover whether or not a browser has javascript enabled, and if not, inform them of why your site will not work.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, and you should, too. Drupal does it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
...
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Good grief, and what does that mess gain Drupal and users thereof?

Comment: So, you think we should be forced to have our sites be backwards compatible with every browser ever made ever?

Comment: Depends on how good you are. I'd let me IDE type that redundant stuff.

Comment: I'd argue that Drupal in and of itself is not a great indicator, or is any other single technology cited as an example.

Comment: I wasn't saying do it *because* Drupal does it. I was giving an example of how to do it and siting my source. I happen to know of a Drupal site (whitehouse.gov) so I copied the source from there.

Comment: That dog's breakfast is only needed if you're shipping to browsers that predate javascript AND xml parsers. In other words, it's not sensible to actually use.